# Upload multiple files using ajax and spring mvc

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload multile files using FormData and spring.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple id="upload-files">
```

JS code:

```
var ajaxData = new FormData();
var files = $('#upload-files').prop('files');
for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    ajaxData.append('file['+i+']', files[i]);
}
ajaxData.append("file", files);
$http.post('../rest/upload', ajaxData, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
    transformRequest: angular.identity
});
```

Spring Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String upload(
        @RequestParam ArrayList<MultipartFile> files
){
    System.out.println(files.size());
    return null;
}
```

However, count of files is coming out to be 0 on submitting the request with multiple files. On using array notation `MultipartFile[] files` instead of ArrayList , it gives 400, Bad Request.

How to make spring controller work with multiple files? I am unable to find solution on other SO questions.

Comment: Did you try to relocate List<MultipartFile> to an object and configured CommonsMultipartResolver and InternalResourceViewResolver on spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: Did you add encType properly in form submit button? e.g. <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadFile.jsp" method="POST"> and input type as <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />

Answer (score 5):

By default, the `DataBinder` tries to bind request parameters to target object with convention - the parameter names from the request (the FormData in your case) and in the controller's action must match.

In your case you should rename `file[i]` to `files[i]`:

```
for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++){
    ajaxData.append('files[' + i + ']', files[i]);
}
```

**OR** rename action's parameter from `ArrayList<MultipartFile> files` to `ArrayList<MultipartFile> file`

---

Also, delete this line `ajaxData.append("file", files);` (which is right after the for loop), because it is setting a parameter with the same name and some kind of glitch can occur.

Hope this helps.